# Finding the maximum value from an expression using a loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I want to find the maximum value using the second derivative of the the expression when `x` is between `0` and `1`. In other words I am taking the derivative of `cox(x^2)` twice to get the second derivative resulting in `- 2*sin(x^2) - 4*x^2*cos(x^2)`, then I want to evaluate this second derivative at `x = 0` to `x = 1`, and display the `maximum` value of the populated values.

I have:

```
syms x
f = cos(x^2);
secondD = diff(diff(f));

for i = 0:1
y = max(secondD(i))
end
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to what kind of help you are looking for?

Comment: @purple please see edit

Comment: You find the maximum of f(x) by setting the derivative to zero, df(x)/dx=0, and solving for x. You can numerically find the zero crossing of a function, this is much easier than numerically finding the maximum.

Comment: @CrisLuengo my problem is evaluating such equation in matlab. Can you as i tried `solve(f, 0,x)` without success

Comment: If MATLAB cannot solve it analytically, it surely can solve it numerically. See `fzero`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily by `subs` and `double`:

```
syms x
f = cos(x^2);
secondD = diff(diff(f));

% instead of the for loop
epsilon = 0.01;
specified_range = 0:epsilon:1;
[max_val, max_ind] = max(double(subs(secondD, specified_range)));
```

Please note that it is a numerical approach to find the maximum and the returned answer is not completely correct all the time. However, by increasing the `epsilon`, you can expect a better result in general (again in some cases it is not completely correct).

Comment: in this case I get 0 for x =1 i am expecting about 3.8

Comment: @Fil Not true. `0` is the value of the function for the first element which is `0`! The value of the function on `1` is around `-3.8`.

Comment: I see, I have corrected it using the `abs` function. thank u